# Docker performance when running on LVM

Tags: docker, linux, performance

It seems that when using overlay2 storage driver, docker is much slower when using a LVM compared to without a LVM (ext4 filesystem in both cases, same machine).

**Questions:**

1. Is this intended/expected?
2. Is a LVM a recommended setup for docker usage?
3. Is it worth to try other storage drivers (e.g. devicemapper with direct-lvm)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an docker expert, just responding from my experience and limited knowledge.

1. It's expected, yes.
2. That's a matter of opinion. I'd say no, but that's very subjective.
3. Yes.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/